# How to change string to timeformat with numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a CSV file, one of colons value is timestamps but when I use numpy.getfromtxt it change it to string. My goal is to create a graph  but with normal time format.

this is my array:

```
array([('0:00:00',), ('0:00:00.001000',), ('0:00:00.002000',),
   ('0:00:00.081000',), ('0:00:00.095000',), ('0:00:00.195000',),
   ('0:00:00.294000',), ...
```

this is my code:

```
col1 = numpy.genfromtxt("mycsv.csv",usecols=(1),delimiter=',',dtype=None, names=True)
```

Comment: so far I tried time.strptime("%H:%M:%S.%f") in dtype but it does not work

Comment: You could use dtype='datetime64', no?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and it is like so:

```
convertfunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

col1 = numpy.genfromtxt('00_12_4B_00_58_9B.csv',usecols=(1),delimiter=',',dtype=("object",float), names=True, converters={1: convertfunc})
```

But what I need to do more is to set ms values to 0 if they are missing and not None